# Problem after logging out the sytsem in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: login, logout

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed on my system. 2 users are there me ,hduser(i.e., hadoop). now when i logout of any user the system goes blank. A black screen appears with nothing written on it?After that i will again restart the system from laptop.Any solution???

Answer (score 0):

This issue had been reported before with several possibilities to the error.

This issue have several possibilities.

One of the most common possibility is  hardware incompatibility. If you are using a latest version laptop, the hardware may not be supporting Ubuntu 10.04 operations.

Second one is, your lightdm may be crashing. This is the program responsible for display systems in Ubuntu.

Different people have different solutions for this issue like 
`http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1477795`
`https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/549632`
`https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/529882`

You could try one of the solutions mentioned in these thread.

My opinion is, when you experience this issue, Try to go to one of the non GUI terminals of Ubuntu. This could be achieved by using the key combination `alt+ctrl+(f1/f2/f3../f6)`. Once you get hold of one of these screen, login into the terminal. 
Then restart the lightdm  using

`sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: K i will look forward to it.